# Image not displaying in chrome Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am dynamically loading an image in a div. Image is loading in firefox but not in chrome.I have disabled adblock but still image is not loading.

I am storing image path in database and image in a root folder. Any help will be really appreciated.

```
str.Append("<div style='padding:20px;margin-top:10px;'>");
                str.Append("<table  border='1' style='width:350px;margin-top:20px;font-family:arial;font-size:12px;'>");

                str.Append("<tr><td style='width: 150px;'><center><img src='" + Imagesrc + "' alt='2'  style='width:150px;height:150px'/>"
                    + "</center></td></tr>");

                str.Append(" </table>");

                str.Append("</div>");

Imagesrc = "Images/img1.png";
```

Comment: this might be the problem with image URL. try to put ~ in front of path to specify that image is in root folder

Comment: So you're setting `ImageSrc` after you already concatenated it into your `img` tag? That doesn't make logical sense, the order should be reversed. What does the resulting HTML look like?

Comment: Imagesrc = "Images/img1.png"; this is just an example of the value coming to Imagesrc variable

Comment: @frebinfrancis i tried putting ~ in front of the path...but still not loading the image.As i said the problem is only with chrome.It is working fine with firefox.

Comment: try to use inspect element in google chrome or firebug in firefox to check the url of that image and make appropriate changes in the url so that you can see the image in browser.

Comment: Image is loading in firefox.The problem is only with chrome.Strange thing is if i copy/paste image url in a seperate tab in chrome the image is loading.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Imagesrc = @"Images/img1.png";
```

or

```
Imagesrc = "Images//img1.png";
```

But your code is very strange. Why you generate your web layout dynamically? Why you dont use ASP.NET MVC or WebForms?

Comment: There is no need to use a string literal or a double forward slash. That's only necessary if you're using a backslash, as in `@"C:\Users\coolperson\Documents\"` or `"C:\\Users\\coolperson\\Documents\\"`.